# complex objects for WCF?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, wcf

I'm having a problem calling the WCF service from JQuery AJAX. GetUserDetails works fine unless I try add this code to the User class:

```
[DataMember]
public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
```

After code is added I get error status 12152. If I comment out [DataMember] attribute of the Role method everything works.

Here's OperationContract for the method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped
    )]
User GetUserDetails(string userName);
```

And User class:

```
    [DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Role))]
public class User 
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Company { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Comments { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual bool LoggedIn { get; set; }

}
```

Role class

```
[DataContract]
public class Role
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you turned on WCF diagnostics to get the underlying exception?

Comment: I have this code in web config:                                  <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true"      includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/> but still in response I'm getting only status 12152. Please see screenshot: [link](http://ScrnSht.com/sjrgle)

Comment: There is more to it than that.  You can get much more information by doing this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: what does your browser return if you 'manually' poll the same URL as your AJAX call? PS: you can embed images in your post by clicking the image icon in the editor

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your comments. Enabling tracing helped to me find the problem. The problem was because I used NHibernate, Role object were lazy loaded and proxy for that object were used and that proxy object couldn't be serialized.

```
Type 'DecoratorAopProxy_70ab9a81c5b84b6dbf624b0a94f7028e' cannot be ISerializable and have DataContractAttribute attribute.
```

I have turned off lazy loading and that solved the issue. Thank you very much!